# MongoDB: updateOne query , set unset values if exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I am looking to create a mongodb query to update once document such a way that it will set a few fields with values and if there are already fields available (other fields which are not is set) unset them.

I did it like this:

```
db.collection('collectionName").find({"itemId": itemsDataArray[i].itemId }).updateOne(
                { "$unset" :
                    {
                        "field1": 1,
                        "field2": 1,
                        "field3": 1
                    }
                },
                { "$set": 
                    { 
                       "field4" : "value",
                       "field5" : "value"

                    }
                })
```

Now the problem is if the field1,2 or 3 are not there in the document then the query fails to set the field 4 and 5.

Is there any flag which i am missing in the mongo query?
Please help.

EDIT: **Solution**

```
db.collection('collectionName').find({"itemId": itemsDataArray[i].itemId }).updateOne(
                { "$unset" :
                    {
                        "field1": 1,
                        "field2": 1,
                        "field3": 1
                    }, 
                  "$set": 
                    { 
                       "field4" : "value",
                       "field5" : "value"

                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got the braces wrong.

You're using `.collection(...).find(...).updateOne({"$unset" :{} }, {"$set": {} })`.

You should use `.collection(...).find(...).updateOne({"$unset" :{}, "$set": {} })`.

Note that you're missing the `filter` argument to `updateOne`. Have you looked at [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)?

Lastly, it's probably a copy/paste mistake, but the quotes are mismatched in the collection access (`collection('name")`).

Comment: Thanks. The issue was the use of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Please read docs for [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/).

First parameter is a filter. What you are trying to achieve should be:

```
db.d.updateOne(
    {"itemId": itemsDataArray[i].itemId},
    { 
        "$unset":
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 1,
                "field3": 1
            },

        "$set": 
        { 
           "field4" : "value",
           "field5" : "value"

        }
    }
)
```